# Planting bare root perennials

Tags: pruning, planting, perennials

I bought some bare root perennial flowers which have some fairly long roots attached.

Should I trim up these roots before planting? As is, the hole will need to be very wide lest the roots be twisted around, which doesn't sound ideal.

Comment: What are the perennials that you want to plant?

Comment: @Jurp: mostly echinacea, i.e. purple cone flower

Comment: Most species of echinacea have tap roots, so the hole probably needs to be deep, not wide. In winter, bare-root perennials are often little more than a bunch of roots, so it's not always obvious which is the "right way up" to plant them!